# Set ng-model on directive from parent controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have 2 of the same directive next to each other (`<jd-autocomplete>`), where the 2nd's `ng-model` value should be set depending on the selected value of the 1st.

The `<jd-autocomplete>` directive takes a scope attribute called `ac-change` (function) which gets called when the `<input>` inside of that directive changes.

It would look like this:

```
<form>
    <jd-autocomplete ac-change="doChange" ng-model="entry.vendor"></jd-autocomplete>
    <jd-autocomplete ng-model="entry.category"></jd-autocomplete>
</form>
```

Where `$scope.doChange = function(){}` exists as a method on the parent controller, how would I access and set the 2nd directive's model inside of that function?

Here's my plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/fTFM67wBcYtK6qdnjhNY?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Forked you [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kHNfWFZvKfc9lOkg7vOW?p=preview)

On edit of first text box you will have same value in your second text box.. Now you can write your custom login inside doChange handler.

```
app.controller('AddFormController', [
    '$rootScope',
    '$scope',
    '$element',
    '$http',

    function ($rootScope, $scope, $element, $http){
        $scope.vendors      = [{'vendor_name':'hi', 'category_name': 'food'},{'vendor_name':'dude', 'category_name': 'food'}];
        $scope.categories   = [{'category_name': 'food'},{'category_name': 'gas'}];

$scope.entry = {};

  $scope.wrapper = {};
        $scope.wrapper.doChange = function(obj){
            console.log(obj);
            $scope.entry.category = obj;
        };

    }
]);
```

Comment: Oh.. Wow! All I had to do was make `entry` an object of the parent. Way easier than I was hoping

Comment: yes, and this is the way to work with angularjs. If you are sharing something across directives or across controllers or across directive and controller then share it through object, instead of scope directly. It will reduce complexity, you will have better control on your code.